# How can I get an object's property name without redundant 'name' key inside the object? And how to return 'name' of a user-provided undefined object?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there any way to get the property name of an object without having some sort
of redundant 'name' property inside the object itself? This will mainly be used
in cases where we a user tries to fetch an object that doesn't exist.

For example:

```
let myObject = {
    favoriteListing: {
        name: 'favoriteListing',
        category: 'favorite',
        action: 'add'
    },
    sendListing: {
        name: 'sendListing',
        category: 'send',
        action: 'sms'
    }
};

let displayObj = (object) => {
    if (!object) {
        console.warn(`Whoa, cowboy. ${object.name} does not exist!`);
        return;    
    } else {
        return object;
    }
}
```

And expected vs actual output:

```
displayObj(myObject.favoriteListing);
/*
Output:
    => { name: 'favoriteListing', category: 'favorite', action: 'add' }
*/

displayObj(myObject.dammitBatman);
/*
Desired Output:
    => Whoa, cowboy. 'dammitBatman' does not exist!

Actual Output:
    => TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
*/
```

Comment: you could throw an exception in an if statement

Comment: would separating the object and a property name help you?

Comment: Another approach has been posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to test whether the property exists before referring to it.

```
let displayObj = (object, property) => {
    if (!object[property]) {
        console.warn(`Whoa, cowboy. ${property} does not exist!`);
        return;    
    } else {
        return object;
    }
}


displayObj(myObject, "joe");

displayObj(myObject, "sendListing");
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. This looks like the way to go! Easy enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would separating the object and a property name help you? As in:

```
let displayObj = (obj,propertyName) => {    
    return obj && obj[propertyName] || console.warn(`Whoa, cowboy. ${propertyName} does not exist!`);
}
```

Here we test for if object is not undefined and return it's named property or log an error.
Concise! And javascripty (-:

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the name redundatn `name` properties from `myObject` object and modify the `displayObj()` function like this:

```
let displayObj = (obj, name)=>{
    if(!obj[name]) {
        console.warn("Whoa, cowboy. " + name + " does not exist!`");
        return
    }else return obj[name];
}
```

**Edited**
Even more

```
let displayObj = (obj, name)=>{
    if(!obj){ 
        console.warn("Unable to get " + name + "property of " + obj)
        return
    }
    if(!obj[name]) {
        console.warn("Whoa, cowboy. " + name + " does not exist!`");
        return
    }
    return obj[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
myObject.hasOwnProperty("favoriteListing")
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions could not know which parameter belongs to  which object and their property names. So, it is impossible to get desired results as you expected.

But, thanks to javascript, we make this possible by a few modification.

The snippet below just designed considering your requirements.

```js
const PROPERTY = Symbol('property');
class InvalidProperty {
  constructor(propertyName) {
    this[PROPERTY] = propertyName;
  }
  get property(){
    return this[PROPERTY];
  }
}

function createProxy(obj){
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop){
      if(!target.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        return new InvalidProperty(prop);
      }
      return target[prop];
    }
  });
}

let displayObj = (object) => {
    if (object instanceof InvalidProperty) {
        console.warn(`Whoa, cowboy. ${object.property} does not exist!`);
    } else {
        console.log(object);
    }
}


let myObject = createProxy({
    favoriteListing: {
        name: 'favoriteListing',
        category: 'favorite',
        action: 'add'
    },
    sendListing: {
        name: 'sendListing',
        category: 'send',
        action: 'sms'
    }
});


displayObj(myObject.sendListing);
displayObj(myObject.thisDoesNotExist);
```